# Debug non-linking header files in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, header-files, linker-errors

Just wondering if anyone has an idea about how to solve this issue.

Thanks so much!!

With this code in main.cpp:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Chess
//
//  Created by Akshar Ramkumar on 9/29/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Akshar Ramkumar. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include "DataStructures.hpp"


int main() {
    struct Piece {
        int Type;
        int x;
        int y;
        bool Captured;
        bool Color;
        char pictfile[7];
    };



    struct Piece All[32];
    setup(All);
    return 0;
}
```

And this code in DataStructures.hpp:

```
#ifndef DataStructures_hpp
#define DataStructures_hpp
void setup(struct Piece All[32]);


#endif
```

And this code in DataStructures.cpp:

```
//
//  Classes.cpp
//  Chess
//
//  Created by Akshar Ramkumar on 10/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Akshar Ramkumar. All rights reserved.
//Pawn = 0
//Rook = 1
//Knight = 2
//Bishop = 3
//King = 4
//Queen = 5

struct Piece {
    int Type;
    int x;
    int y;
    bool Captured;
    bool Color;
    char pictfile[7];
};

void setup(struct Piece All[32]){

    int TypeArray[32]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5};
    int xValues[32]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,7,1,6,2,5,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,7,1,6,2,5,3,4};
    int yValues[32]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7};


    for (int i=0;i<32;i++){
        All[i].Type = TypeArray[i];
        All[i].y = yValues[i];
        All[i].x = xValues[i];
        All[i].Color = true;
        All[i].Captured = false;


        if (i>15){
            All[i].Color = false;
        }


    }
}
```

I get an error saying: No matching function for call to “Setup” in main.cpp. Any Ideas

Comment: struct Piece All[32]; you dont  put the struct/class/union when making object of your own user defined types. Piece All[32]; is fine

Comment: On what line of the code?

Comment: You have defined two `Piece` structures. You should move it's definition to one place, DataStructures.hpp would be the best in your case. Another thing is that you don't have to use struct keyword as mentioned before.

Comment: @A.Ramkumar all of the struct Piece All[32];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic skeleton of your code :

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Chess
//
//  Created by Akshar Ramkumar on 9/29/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Akshar Ramkumar. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
namespace DataStructures {
    struct Piece {
        int Type;
        int x;
        int y;
        bool Captured;
        bool Color;
        char pictfile[7];
    };

     void setup(Piece* pieces) {
          //TODO
     }
};

int main() {

    DataStructures::Piece All[32];
// Initialize All[32] here
    DataStructures::setup(All);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: 1. Putting everything in one file is a bad practice. 2. Creating a class containing nothing more than one static method either. You could use a namespace instead. (or/and keep having separate elements in different files)

Comment: I want to show basic skeleton of code , thats why I put all into one file

Comment: Now is better but I'm a little bit uncomfortable with a method in Data**Structures** namespace ;)

Comment: Just because of the given name. (the **Structures** part). It's confusing, nothing more. Would you like to have a class named Dog inside the Cats namespace?